# Show that $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\arcsin\frac{1}{\sqrt{ n}} $ convergence

Tags: analysis

Show that $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\arcsin\frac{1}{\sqrt{ n}} $ convergence positive serie

Soluctions:

We know that $\sin(x) < x$ then $\arcsin(x) \geq x$

then  $\arcsin(\frac{1}{\sqrt{ n}}) \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{ n}} \geq \frac{1}{n}$

we know that $1 / n$ is divergent, then by purchase criteria we have $\arcsin(\frac{1}{\sqrt{ n}})$ as a result $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\arcsin\frac{1}{\sqrt{ n}} $ is divergent

I want to know if my answer is good

can someone review,please

Comment: Use limit comparison test with $a_n=1/\sqrt{n}$ and $b_n=\arcsin(1/\sqrt{n})$.

Answer (score 1):

When n approaches infinity, we can know that $\arcsin\frac{1}{\sqrt{ n}} $ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{ n}} $ are equivalent infinity.

```
Limit[ArcSin[1/Sqrt[n]]/(1/Sqrt[n]), n -> Infinity]
```

So series $\arcsin\frac{1}{\sqrt{ n}} $ diverges.